# Wrong values while appending 2 list obtain from OpenCV image reading

Tags: python, opencv

I'm reading images from 2 folders and then appending it. I'm using the following code to do it.

```
import cv2
import os

path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/Val1"
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        label = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split("/")[-1]

        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
            labels.append(label)
    return images, labels
train_data_all_pos = load_images_from_folder("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/Val1")
train_features_pos = train_data_all_pos[0]
train_labels_pos = train_data_all_pos[1]
print(len(train_features_pos))
print(len(train_labels_pos))

path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/Val2"

train_data_all_neg = load_images_from_folder("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/Val2")
train_features_neg = train_data_all_neg[0]
train_labels_neg = train_data_all_neg[1]

print(len(train_features_neg))
print(len(train_labels_neg))

train_features = np.append(train_features_pos, train_features_neg)
train_labels = np.append(train_labels_pos, train_labels_neg)

print(len(train_features))
print(len(train_labels))
```

Total images in `Val1` is 163 and `Val2` is 340. But when I'm appending, for Labels I'm getting 503, but for features I'm getting value in millions. Each image dimension is 64*64*3. So, the total value I'm getting is `6180864`, which is just 64*64*3*503.

The problem I'm having is the dimension of features and images are not the same. I'm making a mistake here, but not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html -- seems to me you should specify `axis=0` there. "The axis along which values are appended. If axis is not given, both arr and values are flattened before use."

Comment: @DanMašek: Perfect! This solved my problem.